# weird output when i run sh file.

Tags: terminal, scripting, sh

I've made a sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

myvariable=Hello

anothervar=Fred

echo $myvariable $anothervar
echo

sampledir=/etc

ls $sampledir
```

when i run it with

```
$sh simplevariables.sh
```

I get this output:

```
afpovertcp.cfg              networks
afpovertcp.cfg~orig         networks~orig
aliases                 newsyslog.conf
aliases.db              newsyslog.d
apache2                 nfs.conf
asl                 nfs.conf~orig
asl.conf                notify.conf
auto_home               ntp-restrict.conf
auto_master             ntp.conf
auto_master~orig            ntp_opendirectory.conf
autofs.conf             openldap
bashrc                  pam.d
bashrc_Apple_Terminal           passwd
bashrc~previous             passwd~orig
com.apple.IPConfiguration.plist     paths
com.apple.screensharing.agent.launchd   paths~orig
csh.cshrc               periodic
csh.cshrc~orig              pf.anchors
csh.login               pf.conf
csh.login~orig              pf.os
csh.logout              php-fpm.conf.default
csh.logout~orig             php.ini.default
cups                    php.ini.default-previous
defaults                postfix
dnsextd.conf                ppp
efax.rc~previous            profile
emond.d                 profile~orig
find.codes              protocols
find.codes~orig             protocols~previous
fstab.hd                racoon
fstab.hd~previous           rc.common
ftpd.conf               rc.common~previous
ftpd.conf.default           rc.netboot
ftpusers                resolv.conf
ftpusers~orig               rmtab
gettytab                rpc
gettytab~orig               rpc~previous
group                   rtadvd.conf
group~previous              rtadvd.conf~previous
hosts                   security
hosts-original              services
hosts.equiv             services~previous
hosts~orig              shells
irbrc                   shells~orig
kern_loader.conf            snmp
kern_loader.conf~previous       ssh
krb5.keytab             ssl
localtime               sudo_lecture
locate.rc               sudoers
mach_init.d             sudoers.d
mach_init_per_login_session.d       sudoers~orig
mach_init_per_user.d            syslog.conf
mail.rc                 syslog.conf~previous
mail.rc~orig                ttys
man.conf                ttys~previous
manpaths                xtab
master.passwd               zprofile
master.passwd~orig          zshrc
nanorc
```

Any suggestions how to just get an output of
    Hello Fred

What should I do to get rid of all the unnecessary Garbo and just the output?

This happens to all the other scripting files that I run as well. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove this

```
sampledir=/etc

ls $sampledir
```

it is printing out the contents of /etc, and you are not seeing your wanted output

Comment: could you mark it as answered and upvote me if it helped